# how do i go about fixing this error? i am trying to run model but keep getting this key error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is my code all seems well till i ru n it and just before it runs i get an error

```py
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f'logs\{NAME}')

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=10, save_best_only=True, mode='max'))

train_y= np.asarray(train_y) 
validation_y= np.asarray(validation_y)

history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,

    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),

    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
```

this is the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Enock/.spyder-py3/cryptoRnn.py', wdir='C:/Users/Enock/.spyder-py3')
train data: 69188 validation: 3062
Dont buys: 34594, buys: 34594
VALIDATION Dont buys: 1531, buys: 1531
Train on 69188 samples, validate on 3062 samples
Epoch 1/20
    WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x000001ED8967C1F8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: 
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x000001ED8967C1F8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: 
   64/69188 [..............................] - ETA: 16:11:22Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-37d8bfb90722>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Enock/.spyder-py3/cryptoRnn.py', wdir='C:/Users/Enock/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Enock/.spyder-py3/cryptoRnn.py", line 184, in <module>
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 372, in fit
    prefix='val_')

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 685, in on_epoch
    self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 298, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 965, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 984, in _save_model
    filepath = self._get_file_path(epoch, logs)

  File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1020, in _get_file_path
    return self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)

KeyError: 'val_accuracy'
```

how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change** the name of

> 'val_accuracy' to 'val_acc'

in `filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.3f}.hdf5"` and it should work.

Also, please change the line

```
"models\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=10, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

to

```
"models\{}.model".format(filepath), monitor='val_acc', verbose=10, save_best_only=True, mode='max').
```

Here, you only need to use the first parameter in the .format() function. The issue comes from the fact that you send a lot of parameters instead of a single one to the .format() function.

If these still do not work, you should use 'val_accuracy' in both filepath and checkpoint. If this does not work either, please remove 'val_acc:3f' from your filepath name.

Comment: i did but still giving me the same error:   File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1020, in _get_file_path
    return self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)

KeyError: 'val_acc'

Comment: still dont get why am getting that error here is the code again::::filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max'))

Comment: I found the issue. "models\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=10, save_best_only=True, mode='max'). Here, you only need to use the first parameter in the .format() function.

Comment: i did but the error is there:    File "C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1020, in _get_file_path
    return self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)

KeyError: 'val_acc'

Comment: the code :   filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath), monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

Comment: Okay. Please remove then the  "{val_acc:.3f}" from the checkpoint file name. It should work fine.

Comment: Either remove it altogether, or use 'val_accuracy' both in filepath and checkpoint. Hope one of those two solve your problem!

Comment: i just took it out then this appears:  filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath), monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

Comment: with this error:  InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [] [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [64 1] [y (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [64 60]
  [[node loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal/Assert/Assert (defined at C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_50507]

Function call stack:
distributed_function

Comment: That is another issue. Please mark my answer as solving/ at least upvote it since it solved your problem. For the other issue, kindly ask another question (I will personally look for it). Thank you.

Comment: hi Timbus Calin please help with new issue as promised